# PERL script required transfer xml file from 1 FTP server to another, split into small files

Tags: xml, perl, file, ftp, split

I am a complete stranger to PERL and need some valuable help

Here is my problem

I need to copy a file from ftp server A and place the file into ftp server B
When doing this i need to read that file contents and split that big file by matching the pattern of open and ending tags combination and create individual small files and place them in destination ftp server B.

For example if the file name is 20100921.xml and if sample has below format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
    </child>
    <child>
        <code></code>
        <text></text>
    </child>
 </parent>
```

In the original XML there are lot of child tags instances; i will need to make separate files whose contents will be the ones between  tags.
In this case there will be 2 new files to be created.
Individual file names could be like 20100921_1.xml

Everyday there will be only 1 file and the file name will have current date.

Can anyone help me with PERL that can do the above.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've asked several questions by implication here. Which one are you after the answer to? Perhaps asking a question along the lines of "How do I use Perl to split and XML file into multiple XML files?" would be more useful. The FTP side is a completely different question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xml_split](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_split/xml_split) for this, probably something like `xml_split -l 1 -b 20100921 big.xml`.

xml_split comes with [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig), so it is indeed in Perl, which doesn't really matter, unless you want to extract the relevant code from the tool and include in yours.